# Return multiple of string characters

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a function where an input of a string is taken in and the output returns a string of how many times the number is repeated. For example if my string is "1111223444" it will return "41221334", because there are four 1's, two 2's, one 3, and three 4's. So an input of "2234467" would return "2213241617". I am not sure if a dictionary would be the best way to implement it and I am really confused. I have started the function however don't know where to go from here. Any tips or resources will be helpful.

```
     func stringOutput(input: String) -> String {

         var result = ""
         var lastCharacter: Character
         var count = 0
         var countDict: [String: Int] = [:]

         for item in input {
          countDict[item] as Character

             }

      return result
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the snippet below.

```
func stringOutput(input: String) -> String {
    var result = ""
    var lastKnownCharacter: Character? = nil
    var lastKnownCharacterCount: Int = 0

    for character in input {
        if lastKnownCharacter == nil {
            lastKnownCharacter = character
            lastKnownCharacterCount = 1
        } else if lastKnownCharacter == character {
            lastKnownCharacterCount += 1
        } else {
            result.append("\(lastKnownCharacterCount)\(lastKnownCharacter!)")
            lastKnownCharacter = character
            lastKnownCharacterCount = 1
        }
    }
    result.append("\(lastKnownCharacterCount)\(lastKnownCharacter!)")
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function computes the next term of the [Look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence). Here is an implementation (essentially taken from [Leetcode 38: The “count-and-say” sequence](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/213714/35991) on Code Review). Instead of traversing the string, we directly search for the next index of a character different from the current one. Neither the first nor the last run has be be treated specially:

```
extension String {

    func lookAndSay() -> String {
        var result = ""
        var fromIndex = startIndex // Start of current run
        while fromIndex != endIndex {
            let char = self[fromIndex] // Current character
            // Find start of next run
            let toIndex = self[fromIndex...].firstIndex(where: { $0 != char }) ?? endIndex
            // Compute length of run, and append it to the result
            let len = distance(from: fromIndex, to: toIndex)
            result += "\(len)\(char)"
            // Continue with next run
            fromIndex = toIndex
        }
        return result
    }
}

print("1111223444".lookAndSay()) // 41221334
print("2234467".lookAndSay()) // 2213241617
```